# Remove carriage return and newline feeds within a list of dictionaries - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a JSON file which I am reading into my Python script, flattening and then exporting it as a CSV.

My problem is that I noticed there are various carriage returns and newline feeds within the JSON file so it's messing up the whole structure of the CSV.

*Updated* Current Code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.core._match_conditions import MatchConditions
from azure.storage.filedatalake._models import ContentSettings
from pandas import json_normalize
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np

mongo_client = MongoClient("XXXX") 
db = mongo_client.scaling
table = db.planning
document = table.find()
docs = list(document)
docs = json_normalize(docs) 
docs['pressure'] = docs['pressure'].str.strip().str.replace(" \r\n","")
docs.to_csv("planning.csv", sep = ",",index=False)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXX\V2.py", line 16, in <module>
    docs['pressureLevels'] = docs['pressureLevels'].str.strip().str.replace(" \r\n","")
  File "XXXX.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5456, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "XXXX\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 180, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "XXXX\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 154, in __init__
    self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
  File "XXXX\.venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 218, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

How do I get rid of the carriage returns, newline feeds when there's an integer present in the dictionary?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does the JSON file look like, and what's your code for reading it?

Comment: **Instead of the for loop to fix the JSON and then normalize it, why not the other way around.** That would help you to take advantage of the vectorized functions that pandas provides with str methods. Check my answer for details.

Comment: Can you try printing `json_normalize(docs)` and scrolling down to see if the data looks as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working solution to remove carriage returns and newline feeds in a list of dictionaries.

Firstly, you use `json.dumps` which takes a dictionary as input and returns a string as output to enable you to use `.replace` as it only works with strings.

Once the newline feeds and carriage returns have been removed from the string, the string can now be converted back to a dictionary using `json.loads` which will take a string as input and returns a dictionary as an output.

```
docs2 = json.dumps(docs)
docs2 = doc2.replace(r"\n",'').replace(r"\r\n",'').replace(r"\r",'')
docs2 = json.loads(docs2)
docs2 = json_normalize(docs2)
print(docs2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `df.json_normalize` followed by `str.replace` after `str.strip` (instead of the other way around).

**This will let you take full advantage of the vectorized methods of `str` that pandas provides. That way you can skip the explicit for loop!** -

```
docs =  [
{'isActive': 1, 'description': 'teleconference call.\n\n'}, 
{'isActive': 1, 'description': 'calls to review capacity.\n'}, 
{'isActive': 1, 'description': 'communications \r\n.'}
]

df = pd.json_normalize(docs)
df['description'] = df['description'].str.strip().str.replace(" \r\n","")
print(df)
```

```
   isActive                description
0         1       teleconference call.
1         1  calls to review capacity.
2         1            communications.
```

Now you can save this to csv or change it further.

Comment: this seems like the best way to do it, the example above works but for some reason when I flatten the json file which I imported and try replace the carriage returns and newline feed using the `str.replace` and `str.strip` it produces this error: `Can only use .str accessor with string values`

Comment: Does your description have any `None` values?

Comment: no it doesn't have `None` value. I've also updated the code so you can see how i'm doing it and what error i'm getting

Comment: Can you post the `docs['pressure']` where it fails? If the code works on the sample but doesnt on the actual list, only possiblity is that the `docs['pressure']` doesnt have a consistent format.

Comment: Can you add the complete trace from the error?

Comment: It seems that `docs['pressure']` has some rows with different formats. Try printing `docs` once, after the `pd.json_normalize`

Comment: this is the output for `docs['pressure']` after json_normalize: `[{'isActive': True, 'pressure': 2, 'actions': [{'isActive': True, 'description': 'Ensure  place in Majors\r\n'}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227695/discussion-between-user3396351-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error since you are trying to use strip with `int` object.

Try this:

```
for i in docs:
    x = {}
    for k, v in i.items():
        if type(v) == str:
            x[k.strip()] = v.strip().replace("\r\n","")
        else:
            x[k.strip()] = v
    docs2.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little function to do it:

```py
def try_strip(value):
    try:
        return value.strip().replace("\r\n", "")
    except AttributeError:
        return value

docs2 = [{k: try_strip(v) for k, v in d.items()} for d in docs]
# [
#     {'isActive': 1, 'description': 'teleconference call.'}, 
#     {'isActive': 1, 'description': 'calls to review capacity.'}, 
#     {'isActive': 1, 'description': 'communications .'}
# ]
```

The function wouldn't need to use `try ... except` you could use a test using `hasattr()` or `isinstance` instead.